# Object of type SerializerMetaclass is not JSON serializable DRF

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, python-requests

I want to encode data and make a post method using `requests` and `drf`, so example is

```
class ProjectViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    logger = logging.getLogger('django')

    """
    API 
    """
    queryset = Project.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProjectSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.OrderingFilter,
                       filters.SearchFilter, DjangoFilterBackend)
    filterset_class = ProjectFilter
    ordering_fields = ('name', 'owner', 'project')
    ordering = ('name')
    search_fields = ['name']

    # create new execution for this project
    def create(self, request):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            encode_data = json.dumps(serializer)
            response = requests.post(
                url='{}/process'.format(EXAMPLE_URL),
                json=encode_data,
                headers=headers
            )
            logging.debug(f"{self.response}")
            return Response({'response': response})
```

The error for this

`Object of type SerializerMetaclass is not JSON serializable`

and now I'm confused a bit, I suppose I need to encode data because JSON encoding is done in the Response object, but I'm failing to understand the error, so can someone please explain what is wrong here, thanks.

Comment: `json.dumps(serializer.data)` not just serializer.

Comment: @Shakil really, omg I'm blind, thanks, it's working